# Processing a channel concurrently results in unexpected output

Tags: concurrency, go

I have an unbuffered channel that `i` amount of workers take a value from (a filesystem path) and process it (send the file contents over HTTP). I'm running into problem when I increase `i`.

When I run this:

```
paths := make(chan string)

for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    go func() {
        for path := range paths {
            fmt.Println(path)
        }
    }()
}

walkFn := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if !info.IsDir() {
        paths <- path
    }
    return nil
}

filepath.Walk("/tmp/foo", walkFn)
close(paths)
```

It works expectedly and outputs all the contents of `/tmp/foo`:

```
/tmp/foo/2
/tmp/foo/file9
/tmp/foo/file91
/tmp/foo/file90
/tmp/foo/file900
/tmp/foo/file901
/tmp/foo/file902
/tmp/foo/file92
/tmp/foo/file97
/tmp/foo/file93
/tmp/foo/file94
/tmp/foo/file95
/tmp/foo/file96
/tmp/foo/file98
/tmp/foo/file99
```

But when I send the file contents over HTTP, the number of affected files suddenly goes down:

```
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    go func() {
        for path := range paths {
            resp, err := http.Head("https://example.com/" + strings.TrimPrefix(path, rootDir+"/"))
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error: %s\n", err)
                return
            }

            fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", path, resp.Status)
        }
    }()
}
```

the number of affected files reduces from 15 (which is how many exist in the directory), down to 10:

```
/tmp/foo/2: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file901: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file900: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file9: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file90: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file902: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file91: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file92: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file93: 404 Not Found
/tmp/foo/file94: 404 Not Found
```

Here's a table that relates the value of `i` to the number of output lines:

```
+-----+-------+
| `i` | lines |
+-----+-------+
| 1   | 15    |
| 5   | 10    |
| 6   | 9     |
| 15  | 0     |
+-----+-------+
```

Why does this happen and how can I process *all* the channel entries concurrently? Is it a problem with `http` requests?

Comment: Your workers `return` (stop working) on error. Could it be the problem that  sooner or later they all run into an error, leaving no worker alive? Also, does your program block giving the workers enough time to finish or does main exit before all work can be completed?

Comment: Hmm, but if every worker died through that `return` statement, surely you'd see `Error:` in the output? In terms of when the program block exits, I thought it automatically finished when the `paths` channel was empty - is that not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after this line:

```
filepath.Walk("/tmp/foo", walkFn)
```

All paths have been sent through the `paths` channel, this implies that someone received them. However, it does not imply that those receiving goroutines have finished completely.

So when your program exits after `close(paths)`, there are still goroutines working and they get killed because `main` is finished.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. **It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.**

One simple solution is to add

```
select{}
```

at the end of your program. This will make it block forever.

Comment: If I want it to block only until the `paths` channel is empty, how would I do that?

Comment: I figured it - just use `sync.WaitGroup`. Thanks for the pointer!